# Join tables with float and nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have two tables that need to be joined on customer id column.  The problem is that one table has a `float` and the other has `nvarchar(255)`.  In both cases there are records that will be eliminated due to issues with entry (some have no value, a zero or have letters in the field).  I tried creating views and converting the values to either `float` or `nvarchar` and have been unsuccessful.

When I use `cast(ltrim(rtrim(CID)) as text)` I get the values (321K).  This is the `nvarchar(255)` field.  When I try the same with the `float`, I get values in exponential format (`5.10003e+006`)

I need to resolve this as the tables stand right now and will deal with the data integrity issue as I move forward.  I have only been on the job for less than a month, so I am just now finding some of the data issues.

Can anyone suggest a method to allow me to link the two tables together?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, examples of what you've tried and your desired output.

Comment: I am not sure how to attach a file but here are some of the things I have tried:

Comment: Convert float to nvarchar: select cast(str(CID_No,50,0)as nvarchar(255)) as CIDfrom vCust2_Res

Comment: for the nvarchar cast(ltrim(rtrim(CID)) as text  The field CID is generic for customer id in the tables they each have distinct names.  Ultimately I don't care what data format is used as long as I can join based on this value.  I was trying to create views of each of the original tables in order to eliminate the bad values before I did the join.

Comment: This works for me, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc71f/1 if it doesn't work for you we'll need samples of some of the key values which are failing.

Comment: If the 'float' column is just an 'integer in disguise' then converting to an integer string should get you a long way to getting what you want. However, any non integer numbers and it will get 'interesting' as you may have to round the result. Your example of _5.10003e+006_ is an 'integer in disguise'. It is _5100030_ as an integer string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest converting float to numeric. I don't think you can join on float on SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `str(...` on the `FP` field: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx